# Would a question about body language or a specific character in a writing system be off-topic?

Tags: support, off-topic-questions, asking-questions

To be as straight forward as possible, would a question of how body language is perceived by different cultures be off or on topic? And how about a question on the evolution of a specific character in an alphabet?

Answer (score 1):

"Body language" is not language: it is off topic. It might be on topic for some personal-interactions SE. History of writing systems is on topic, and we get various history-of questions on e.g. the development of *w, v, u*.

Comment: Okay, thank you.